# JSON.parse doesn't run

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to get a JSON object from PHP to Javascript. Currently I've got this for my Javascript Code:

```
function GetEvents()
{   
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            var eventObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            alert("Hello");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/includes/GetEvents.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And the PHP it's talking to is this:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbConnect.php';
include_once 'config.php';

class Event
{
     public $eventName;
     public $eventStart;
     public $eventEnd;
}

$prep = "SELECT eventName, eventStart, eventEnd FROM Events ORDER BY eventStart 
DESC";
$statement = $link->prepare($prep);//Prepare Selection from the Database
if($statement)
{
    //Executes SELECT;
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $event = new Event;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $event->eventName = $row['eventName'];
            $event->eventStart = $row['eventStart'];
            $event->eventEnd = $row['eventEnd'];

            echo json_encode($event); //Returns the Event object as a JSON      
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

The issue I'm having is the JSON.parse part in my javascript code doesn't seem to actually work, or at least run considering any code underneath it doesn't run at all while code above it does. So I'm pretty sure this is cause there is an error with JSON.parse but I have no idea what the problem could be.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Any apache log errors? Are you sure the `json_encode` succeeds and you're not just getting the default 500 response?

Comment: It sounds like it's running but throwing an error. If you're using Chrome, his F12 to open the developer tools and see if there are any errors in the console. It's possible your XHR request is not returning the JSON-encoded data (it may be receiving a CORS error or some other non-200 status code) or it's possible your PHP is not generating properly-encoded JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are `echo`ing a JSON string at each iteration of the loop. So the final string is not a valid JSON string. You could create an array, to store the data, and echo the JSON string at the end of process:

```
$data = []; // create an array
$statement = $link->prepare($prep);//Prepare Selection from the Database
if($statement)
{
    //Executes SELECT;
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $event = new Event;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $event->eventName = $row['eventName'];
            $event->eventStart = $row['eventStart'];
            $event->eventEnd = $row['eventEnd'];

            $data[] = $event; // store data into array
        }   
    }
}
echo json_encode($data); // Returns ALL events as a JSON
```

Comment: I recommand you to also add header('application/json') in top of your PHP. This will tell to your browser how to parse the answer, then no need to JSON.parse it.

Comment: @Yanis-git You mean `header("Content-Type: application/json")`, right?